# Is there a simpler way to convert a variant to another variant with const versions of the same types?

Tags: c++, const-correctness, std-variant

In the code below, is there a way to implement `const_foobar foobar_manager::get_foobar() const` in terms of the non-const version without the visit or equivalent code?

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>

struct foo {
    int val;
    std::string str;
};

struct bar {
    double val;
    std::string str;
};

using foobar = std::variant<foo, bar>;
using const_foobar = std::variant<const foo, const bar>;

class foobar_manager {
public:
    foobar get_foobar() {
        // the primary implementation of whatever needs to
        // happen to get the variant we want would go here.
        return foo{ 42, "mumble" };
    }

    const_foobar get_foobar() const {

        // we want to get the const variant in terms of the
        // the getting logic for the non-const case. Can
        // it be done without a visit?

        return std::visit(
            [](auto v)->const_foobar {
                return v;
            },
            const_cast<foobar_manager*>(this)->get_foobar()
        );
    }
};

int main() {
    foobar_manager fm;
    const auto& const_fm = fm;

    auto test1 = fm.get_foobar();
    auto test2 = const_fm.get_foobar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't `const` `variant` sufficient in your case?

Comment: Not directly relevant, but you should be going the other way: the `const` version should be primary, and non-const version implemented in terms of it. `const_cast<foobar_manager*>(this)` exhibits undefined behavior when `*this` object is actually defined as `const`.

Comment: @jarod42, this is example code for SO. In my real code the variant holds reference_wrappers to types or reference_wrappers to const types, where the reference wrapper types are used all over the place as the objects are parts of graph-like structures that are owned by another object. So in this case const variant would make sense but the actual case involves a deeper nesting of const-ness

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik. Good to know. Why is the const cast undefined behavior here?

Comment: [`std::experimental/propagate_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const) might help for the `const std::variant`.

Comment: As you don't have specified a concrete C++ version, you should consider the C++23 feature [deducing this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp23-deducing-this/).

Comment: @jwezorek The const cast has no UB in your example but if the primary implementation is the const version you guard yourself against modifying the object. If you did modify the object then the const overload could potentially be UB.

Comment: You can always memcpy `foobar` to `const_foobar` :P. Not being serious though. I think the `std::visit` is necessary here and you hope that the optimizer cleans it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you can use use the great C++23 feature "deducing this":

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

struct foo
{
    int val;
    std::string str;
};

struct bar
{
    double val;
    std::string str;
};

using foobar = std::variant<foo, bar>;
using const_foobar = std::variant<const foo, const bar>;

struct foobar_manager
{
    auto get_foobar(this auto&& self)
    {
        if constexpr(std::is_const_v<decltype(self)>)
        {
            return const_foobar(foo(42, "mumble"));
        }
        else
        {
            return foobar(foo(42, "mumble"));
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    foobar_manager fm;
    const auto& const_fm = fm;

    auto test1 = fm.get_foobar();
    auto test2 = const_fm.get_foobar();

    return 0;
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GYj13qvnT)

---

Moreover, even with C++17 only (needed for std::variant), you can separate the complex logic to create the initial `foo` in a separate (maybe static) function `get_foo()`, and then simply call this function from the two implementations of `get_foobar`

```
struct foobar_manager
{
    //...
    static auto get_foo() { return foo(42, "mumble"); }
    //...
    auto get_foobar()
    {
        return foobar(get_foo());
    }

    auto get_foobar() const
    {
        return const_foobar(get_foo());
    }
};
```

Comment: the deducing this version is interesting (and I can use C++23 features as long as Microsoft has implemented them) but I don't think it helps my actual use case. I had wanted one of the versions of the function returning the variant to be a virtual member function and then to implement the other one as a non-virtual member function in the base class in terms of the other one but that would mean I do need to convert the variant. Anyway, thanks for the answer, I may just refactor to not use inheritance here .

Comment: @jwezorek: as mentioned above in the comments, I would then also set up the `const` version as the to-be-implemented function (and also consider CRTP). If you then know that, say, always a `foo` is created, you can use `std::get<0>(get_foobar())`. Otherwise, you can and should use a visit as you showed in the OP ... what is actually your problem with this visit? Particularly for many derived classes, it saves you a lot of code. I'd say the use of visit alone is no reason for a refactoring.